# I am finding it Impossible to install Ubuntu 13.04 stuck on splash screen

Tags: installation, 13.04, drivers, ati

**Ubuntu 13.10 (19 august 2913 daily build) works!**

I would prefer not using a in development version but it's ok, even if it's too instable in two months is going to be released.

Even WiFi works out of the box!

Anyway if someone knows a solution it would be better, so please post it if you have an answer.

---

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 on my new notebook, a Toshiba c855-233, Initially I couldn't get further than the grub menu, now I have made a little step forward.

Adding 'nomodeset' to the boot option, I get to the Ubuntu splash screen, which seems to load (the dots are animated), but then the animation stops and I'm stuck on the splash screen.

The graphic card is an AMD Radeon HD 7610M.

EDIT:

Removing "quiet splash" from grub options (and keeping nomodeset) I get to this screen where it once again get stuck: [image]

Sorry for the low quality but opening it at full resolution it is readable. The [fail] is about "restore sound card(s) mixer state(s)"

**Update**

Plugging a VGA monitor into the notobook this is what I get:

[image]

This time it works only without "nomodeset", I'm able to move the mouse but anything else doesn't seem to work

EDIT 2

I accessed a virtual terminal from the VGA screen (it doesn't work in the notebook's one) and here is Xorg log https://www.dropbox.com/s/r314cmcwim9pwdo/0.txt

Comment: Getting linux to work into that laptop is going to be really difficult (check: http://www.linlap.com/toshiba_satellite_c850-c855), including compiling network drivers or using PPAs for a more recent kernel.

Comment: most seems to be problem with wireless not with grapgic card or installation

Comment: Try to boot it with `acpi_backlight=vendor` or `acpi_osi=Linux` boot options.

Comment: nothing... tghis thing is driving me crazy

Comment: after a whole day I decided to try the in development version: 13.10 19 august daily build and it WORKS :))) maybe it won't be very stable but at least I know it works and will probably continue to works! So now I think it's probably somthing landed in the recent kernels

Comment: both 13.04 and 13.10 are development builds. If you are looking for a Long term support version you should install 12.04 or 14.04. Since your solution worked for you, you should write it up as an answer to this question and accept it so that others may benefit from your experience. Thank you!